# Extjs charts in cordova

Tags: cordova, extjs, charts

I am building an ios application using extjs 6 and cordova. When i use charts in my extjs application, the xcode simulator splashes a white screen.

I even added charts to my requires in app.json, still the same. 
Why this happens and what is the solution?

Comment: And when you build production build of your app and preview it in the browser - does the chart work correctly?

Comment: yes it runs correctly in the browser.